Provided weight data has no target variable: sequential/conv2d/kernel
I am building a website that uses facial emotion recognition system on the browser. I built and trained a CNN model in tensorflow and converted it to tensorflow.js. However, while loading the model I keep getting the error,
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Provided weight data has no target variable: sequential/conv2d/kernel
Upon reading some suggestions online, I tried to use tensorflow version 2.15.0 instead of 2.16.0 but it didn't work. I even thoroughly checked the names of weights in my model.json file and the names are exactly the same as the weight names of my model. Here's the weightsManifest block in my model.json file
{"weightsManifest": [{"paths": ["group1-shard1of3.bin", "group1-shard2of3.bin", "group1-shard3of3.bin"], "weights": [{"name": "sequential/conv2d/kernel", "shape": [3, 3, 1, 32], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "sequential/conv2d/bias", "shape": [32], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "sequential/conv2d_1/kernel", "shape": [3, 3, 32, 64], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "sequential/conv2d_1/bias", "shape": [64], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "sequential/conv2d_2/kernel", "shape": [3, 3, 64, 128], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "sequential/conv2d_2/bias", "shape": [128], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "sequential/conv2d_3/kernel", "shape": [3, 3, 128, 128], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "sequential/conv2d_3/bias", "shape": [128], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "sequential/dense/kernel", "shape": [2048, 1024], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "sequential/dense/bias", "shape": [1024], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "sequential/dense_1/kernel", "shape": [1024, 7], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "sequential/dense_1/bias", "shape": [7], "dtype": "float32"}]}]}


Hi @snoopy,Your error shows that your TensorFlow.js is not able to find the weight associated with the variable name in your model’s weight. You need to check that your model was saving correctly. You can also try loading the model in a local environment to check if it is correct or not. If you are still facing an issue, then provide the code. Thank you.
